# converting a nibble to ist ascii value

Tags: c#, data-conversion

I need a solution for converting each nibble of a byte to its ASCII equivalent.  So given:

```
    varA = 0xab;
    char varB = ASCii value of the upper nibble of 0xab 'a' (61)
    char varC = ASCii value of the lower nibble of 0xab 'b' (62)
```

thanks ahead of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert it to hex-string and encode it using ASCII:

```
  byte varA = 0xAB;
  byte[] result = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(varA.ToString("x2"));
  // result[0] is 0x61
  // result[1] is 0x62
```

Comment: thanks @x...  I have been struggling with this for a couple of hours now.  Learn new things daily.  The snippet works great with the exception of handling '0' (zeros)  in the upper nibble which it seems to ignore.  (0x0f the '0' will be dropped

Comment: You must play a little bit with string format : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048(v=vs.110).aspx there you can add leading zeros.